# Cell in a JTable not editable when cell type is not String?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablecelleditor

I have my own `TableModel` implementation designed to show data from a `SQL` database. I have overidden  all the necessary methods, using a String array for column names, an `arraylist<Object[]>` for data and `Class<?>[]` array for all the different types that can be retrieved from the database. I also have a boolean array that dictates which columns are editable and which are not. Before I had everything in the table stored as an Object and hadn't implemented the types part yet and it was working well. Now that I've added the types to the model, I can't edit any column of the int type even though that column is editable in my boolean array. I have overridden the `isEditable()` method to simply return the value from that boolean array, and that returns true on the into column in question - but it is still uneditable. Is this define behaviour or is something wrong? I'm afraid I can't post code at the moment because I'm on my phone, my laptop has no internet connection at the moment and won't until the end of the week. I've searched but Google only shows lots of questions about making cells editable or uneditable, not why you cannot edit an int column.
EDIT: here's a pastebin showing my problem: http://pastebin.com/cYJnyyqy

Using `jdk7` and only the string column is editable, even though `isEditable()` returns true for all columns.

Comment: If you are sure that isEditable returns true, you might want to check the editor of this column.

Comment: see your notice, but for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrated your issue with JTable

Comment: what do you mean by "setting type to int"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm.  I've never used the raw types (e.g. `int.class`) for the getColumnClass().  I've always used the "wrapped" types, e.g. `Integer.class`.

Try changing your  `Class<?>[] types` to use the wrapped classes instead of the primitives.  e.g.

```
 Class<?>[] types = {
            String.class,
            Character.class,
            Integer.class,
            ...
```

This may be needed for Swing to find the correct Renderer/TableCellEditor.  But I'm not sure...

Comment: That lets me edit all columns EXCEPT the char column. Weird. I'll accept this answer but I'd love to know a) why the primitives didn't work and b) why is char still not editable?

Comment: At least in Java 6, JTable.createDefaultEditors() creates a HashMap of editors, but for Number.class.  getDefaultEditor() will (eventually) find that Number is a superclass of Integer and use the appropriate editor.  But int.class doesn't match.  Arguably, this is a bug in the Swing code.  Or yet another example of weird bugs caused by autoboxing.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to follow-up question

> - why is char still not editable

Reason is the default generic editor: it can handle only classes which have a constructor taking a String as parameter, Character doesn't. The way out is a specific custom editor for the Character class.

Here's where JTable.GenericEditor throws up:

```
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                         boolean isSelected,
                                         int row, int column) {
    this.value = null;
    ((JComponent)getComponent()).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
    try {
        Class<?> type = table.getColumnClass(column);
        // Since our obligation is to produce a value which is
        // assignable for the required type it is OK to use the
        // String constructor for columns which are declared
        // to contain Objects. A String is an Object.
        if (type == Object.class) {
            type = String.class;
        }

        // JW: following line fails  
        constructor = type.getConstructor(argTypes);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // JW: so the editor returns a null
        return null;
    }
    return super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
}
```

Here's where JTable handles the null:

```
// JTable.editCellAt(...)
TableCellEditor editor = getCellEditor(row, column);
if (editor != null && editor.isCellEditable(e)) {
    editorComp = prepareEditor(editor, row, column);
    if (editorComp == null) {
        // JW: back out if the comp is null
        removeEditor();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: That's probably why it doesn't like primitives either, none of them use strings or do they even have constructors?